# Instalação bcrypt golang

Tags: golang, bcrypt

Estou com um problema que não consigo resolver e gostaria da ajuda se possível. Sou novo na linguagem golang. Durante um tutorial que estava seguindo a respeito da linguagem, foi criado um script com o pacote bcrypt, seguindo o passo a passo foi informado o comando de instalação do pacote:

```
go get -u golang.org/x/crypto/bcrypt
```

Ao efetuar o processo de forma como havia sido informado, tentei executar o código e apresentava e apresenta a seguinte mensagem de erro:

```
024_Aplicacoes/06_bcrypt.go:9:8: no required module provides package github.com/crypto/bcrypt: go.mod file not found in current directory or any parent directory; see 'go help modules'
```

Já tentei muitos processos:

- Criar a pasta golang.org/x dentro de src
- alterei o conteúdo de go.mod
- tentei instar via github com e sem a pasta github

Estou um pouco chateado por travar em algo tão trivial. Abaixo segue:
Sistema Operacional tentado: Windows10 e Ubunto 20 LTS
versões golang tentadas 1.16.2(ubunutu) / 1.16.3 (windows10)

```
GO111MODULE=""
GOARCH="amd64"
GOBIN=""
GOCACHE="/home/tarcisio/.cache/go-build"
GOENV="/home/tarcisio/.config/go/env"
GOEXE=""
GOFLAGS=""
GOHOSTARCH="amd64"
GOHOSTOS="linux"
GOINSECURE=""
GOMODCACHE="/home/tarcisio/.asdf/installs/golang/1.16.2/packages/pkg/mod"
GONOPROXY=""
GONOSUMDB=""
GOOS="linux"
GOPATH="/home/tarcisio/.asdf/installs/golang/1.16.2/packages"
GOPRIVATE=""
GOPROXY="https://proxy.golang.org,direct"
GOROOT="/home/tarcisio/.asdf/installs/golang/1.16.2/go"
GOSUMDB="sum.golang.org"
GOTMPDIR=""
GOTOOLDIR="/home/tarcisio/.asdf/installs/golang/1.16.2/go/pkg/tool/linux_amd64"
GOVCS=""
GOVERSION="go1.16.2"
GCCGO="gccgo"
AR="ar"
CC="gcc"
CXX="g++"
CGO_ENABLED="1"
GOMOD="/dev/null"
CGO_CFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_CPPFLAGS=""
CGO_CXXFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_FFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_LDFLAGS="-g -O2"
PKG_CONFIG="pkg-config"
GOGCCFLAGS="-fPIC -m64 -pthread -fmessage-length=0 -fdebug-prefix-map=/tmp/go-build770863381=/tmp/go-build -gno-record-gcc-switches"
```

Sei que tenho um imenso caminho pela frente, antes de vir aqui procurar resolução tentei, entretanto sem sucesso.

Answer (score 1):

Me parece que o problema é que você não está dentro da pasta que possui o `go.mod` ao compilar o seu código.

Supondo que eu tenha um projeto com a seguinte estrutura:

```
playground
|_src
| |_main.go
|_go.mod
```

E tente rodar o projeto de fora da pasta `playground` com `go run playground/src/main.go`, eu receberia o erro:

```
playground\main.go:6:2: no required module provides package golang.org/x/crypto/bcrypt: go.mod file not found in current directory or any parent directory; see 'go help modules'
```

Pois o compilador não conseguiu encontrar o `go.mod`, e portanto não conhece as meta-informações do `bcrypt` (como a versão).

---

Agora se eu entro dentro da pasta com `cd playground` e então rodo `go run src/main.go`, o projeto compila e roda perfeitamente.